# Disabled 3rd party software on installation

Tags: system-installation, 14.10

When going through the instillation process for ubuntu 14.10 on a fresh SSD, I disabled "Install third party software" as enabling it seemed to freeze the installation. Now I've successfully installed ubuntu, is there a way I can download all these third party extras as a single collection?

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras.(Make sure Canonical parteners are enabled before running this)

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from comments:

Just do a:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Make sure Canonical partners are enabled before running this!